# Spring controller not triggered

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have this table in a template. There are two buttons in the table cell

```
<td>
<form action="#" data-th-action="@{/userdash}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${acc.recordId}" />                                                 
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="reengage">Re Engage</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="reinvoice">invoice</button>
</form>
```

When `Re Engage` is clicked, I expect the following to be triggered.:

```
/*User dashboard:customer clicks invoice*/
@PostMapping(value="/userdash", params="action=reinvoice")
public ModelAndView reinvoice(@RequestParam String id,Authentication authentication) {
```

when `invoice` is clicked, I expect:

```
/*User dashboard:customer clicks re-engage*/
@PostMapping(value="/userdash", params="action=reengage")
public ModelAndView reengage(@RequestParam String recordId, Authentication authentication) {
```

But only the `reinvoice` method is executed when clicking the `invoice` button.
The `reengage` method fails to execute when clicking the `re engage` button

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//*User dashboard:customer clicks re-engage*/
@PostMapping(value="/userdash", params="action=reengage")
public ModelAndView reengage(@RequestParam String recordId, Authentication 
authentication) {
```

Change `rocordId` to `id` and try. like below:

```
/*User dashboard:customer clicks re-engage*/
@PostMapping(value="/userdash", params="action=reengage")
public ModelAndView reengage(@RequestParam String id, Authentication 
authentication) {
```

The problem in above code is requestParam is expecting `recordId` and you are passing param as `id`